# how to drag imageview left,right,up,and down on Android?

Tags: android, drag

I have an ImageView  which is larger that the Android screen because it was been zoomed how to drag it right,left,up,and down to see the hidden part.

Comment: Usually if the answer works for you you should accept it by clicking on the green check, not just voting +1

Answer (score 1):

Put your ImageView in `ScrollView` nested in `HorizontalScrollView`. That way you will get two scrollbars to navigate.